MUI Datagrid Premium: Add icon in front of the text of grouping column
I am using data grid premium of MUI and i want to add an icon in front of each row cell of grouping column.
This is what the code looks like:
                      <DataGridPremium

                        columns={columns}
                        treeData
                        isGroupExpandedByDefault={() => true}
                        checkboxSelection
                        onRowSelectionModelChange={handleRowSelectionChange}
                        getRowClassName={(params) =>
                            params.indexRelativeToCurrentPage % 2 === 0 ? 'Mui-even' : 'Mui-odd'
                        }
                        getRowId={(row) => {
                            if (row.parent) {
                                return row.path[0]!
                            } else {
                                return row.id
                            }
                        }}
                        rows={rowData}
                        getTreeDataPath={(row) => row.path}
                        sx={{
                            '.MuiDataGrid-filler': {
                                backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5 !important",
                            },
                            '.MuiDataGrid-cell': {
                                display: "flex",
                                justifyContent: "left",
                                alignItems: "center",
                                width: "fit-content",
                                fontWeight: "bold",
                                fontSize: "12px",
                            },
                            '.Mui-even': {
                                background: "#f5f5f5",

                            },
                            '.Mui-header': {
                                background: "#f5f5f5",
                                border: "0.5px solid rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.1)",
                                fontSize: "12px",
                                fontFamily: "Artifakt Element, sans-serif"
                            },
                            '.MuiDataGrid-columnHeader': {
                                background: "#f5f5f5",
                                border: "0.5px solid rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.1)",
                            },
                            backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5"
                        }}
                        groupingColDef={{
                            resizable: false,
                            headerName: "Name",
                            headerClassName: "Mui-header",
                        }}

                    >
                    </DataGridPremium>


I have tried changing groupingColDef but in doing so with renderCell callback, i am unable to achieve the tree structure.

Red marked area in the image is where i want to add the icon
